# JavaScript in tpl?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a JavaScript code in tpl, but when I click the button, nothing happens. here is the code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
// Hide optional fields
$("#hide_op").click(function() {
    $("#optional_fields").hide("slow");    
});

// Show optional fields
$("#show_op").click(function() {
    $("#optional_fields").show("slow");    
});

// Switch the a tags...
$("#toggle a").click(function() {
    $("#toggle a").toggle();    
});
</script>
```

That is the JavaScript code I want to use to drop down extra items; but nothing works. here is the button I'm using "

```
 <div id="toggle">
<a id="hide_op" class="formcss1" style="margin-left: 0; display: none;" onclick="return false;" href="#">Hide optional fields</a>
<a id="show_op" class="formcss1" style="margin-left: 0;" onclick="return false;" href="#">Show optional fields</a>
</div>
```

Then I have the div codes for the java :

```
<div id="optional_fields" style="display: none;">
```

then it ends.

Comment: Did you include jQuery? What does this have to do with TPL? Do you get any errors, what exactly does not work?

Comment: I forgot to add jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot to add jQuery. Thanks Bergi for reminding me about jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add {literal} in start and end

```
<script type="text/javascript">
{literal}
// Hide optional fields
$("#hide_op").click(function() {
    $("#optional_fields").hide("slow");    
});

// Show optional fields
$("#show_op").click(function() {
    $("#optional_fields").show("slow");    
});

// Switch the a tags...
$("#toggle a").click(function() {
    $("#toggle a").toggle();    
});
{/literal}
</script>
```